# High frequency FX data and sample size - possible autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, sample-size, autocorrelation

I have data for EUR/USD at 1 minute intervals for 2003-2018 (approx 5.86million data points)

I have read papers that say that "high frequency data" suffers from "extremely high negative autocorrelation".

Would 1 minute intervals be classed as high frequency?

Does this stop me using a random sample of observations to look at possible upper and lower limits?